# Calculating confidence interval and sample size for data conversions

Tags: statistics, data-conversion, confidence-interval

Say we are converting data from one bookstore application to another. How would one going about calculating the sample size of books to review after the data conversion to be sure 90+-5% of all books converted correctly?

Say our existing book list contains 30 books. How many books would we have to review in the new application after the data conversion to be 85-95% certain that all books converted correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's assume the variable X=Proportion of books converted correctly, distributed normally, with values between 0 and 1

Sample size = this is what we want to determine

Population size = 30
*Existing book list contains 30 books*

Estimated value = 0.90 
That is, the value of X that you think is real.

*90+-5% of all books converted correctly*

If you have no idea of what's the actual value, use 0.5 instead

Error margin = 0.05
The difference between the real value and the estimated value. As you ascertained above, this would be +-5%

Confidence level = 0.95
This is NOT the same as error margin. You are making a prediction, how sure do you want to be of your prediction? This is the confidence level. You gave two values above:
*to be 85-95% certain that all books converted correctly*
So we're going with 95%, just to be sure.

The recommended sample size is **25**
You can use this calculator to arrive to the same results
https://select-statistics.co.uk/calculators/sample-size-calculator-population-proportion/
And it also has a magnificent explanation of all the input values above.

Hope it works for you. Cheers!